# Why does one side of this integrate away and the other doesn't?

Tags: calculus, integration

The last three steps of a paper that I am reading shows this step

$$
\begin{aligned}
=&- \Big( \int q(Z) \log \frac{p(X, Z)}{q(Z)}\ dZ - \int q(Z) \log p(X) \ dZ \Big) \\
=&- \int q(Z) \log \frac{p(X, Z)}{q(Z)}\ dZ + \log p(X) \int q(Z)\ dZ \\
=&- L + \log p(X)
\end{aligned}
$$

The $L$ describes an equation from earlier in the paper, but the important part is that the $\log p(X)$ gets brought out of the integral and then the integral integrates to 1. Why can that be done for the last term but not the first term? Is it because $p$ and $q$ are different distributions?

Comment: Looks like you’re integrating over $z$, and $x$ is independent of $z$, so you can pull $\log p(x)$ out because it doesn’t depend on $z$.

Comment: ok that's what I suspected, thanks

Comment: Are $p(X,Z)$ and $p(X)$ different functions? In that case, it's not a very good idea to use the same letter $p$ for both of them...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In second term $\log {p(X)}$ is a function of **only** $X$ whereas in first term $\log {p(X,Z)}$ is a function of **both** $X$ and $Z$.

$X$ doesn't change in respect to $Z$ so that's why $\log {p(X)}$ is only a constant in respect to $Z$.
Also there should not be a relationship between $Z \text{ and } X$